# Debug python coredump with python callstack

Tags: python, c, linux, gdb, coredump

I'm currently trying to debug a complex multi-threaded python script on a production environment which sometimes crashes using python3.10.10

I can't reproduce the bug on a development environment and the issue seems to come from low-level C libraries so I need to inspect a coredump in order to understand what is happening.

Following this link [Debugging Python C extensions with GDB](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/09/08/debugging-python-c-extensions-gdb#) , I need a python binary compiled with debug symbols, and also python gdb extensions in order to know where the issue occurs into the script.

---

- **Compiling a debug python version**

```
$ wget -c https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.10/Python-3.10.10.tar.xz
$ tar -Jxvf Python-3.10.10.tar.xz
$ mkdir Python-3.10.10/build
$ cd Python-3.10.10/build
$ ../configure --with-pydebug --prefix=~/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug
$ make EXTRA_CFLAGS="-DPy_REF_DEBUG"
$ make install
$ mkdir ~/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/
$ cp build/python-gdb.py ~/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.10-gdb.py
```

---

- **Reproducing the link example**

With the debug version of python, I'm able to reproduce the minimal example using the given `slow.py` script, even though I have to manually load the `python3.10-gdb.py` file into gdb with `source ~/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.10-gdb.py` for `py-*` command to be available into gdb.

```
$ gdb -args ~/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/bin/python3.10d slow.py
(gdb) source ~/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.10-gdb.py
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/bin/python3.10d slow.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Slow function...
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7d6f196 in __GI___select (nfds=nfds@entry=0, readfds=readfds@entry=0x0, writefds=writefds@entry=0x0, exceptfds=exceptfds@entry=0x0, timeout=timeout@entry=0x7fffffffdbc0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/select.c:41
(gdb) py-bt
Traceback (most recent call first):
  <built-in method sleep of module object at remote 0x7ffff7a62450>
  File "/home/user/python_installs/slow.py", line 5, in slow_function
    time.sleep(60 * 10)
  File "/home/user/python_installs/slow.py", line 6, in <module>
    slow_function()
```

I can also successfully have the python binary backtrace with `bt` command.

---

- **Debugging the coredump file**

In order to analyze the issue, I configured the system to dump core files on crashes and  I modified the script launch command in order to use the new debug version of python.

After a while the issue occurred and I could retrieve the generated coredump file.

I tried to use the same approach but using the coredump instead of directly running the script into gdb

- First try

```
$ gdb ~/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/bin/python3.10d 1681210136_python3.10d_157077.coredump
Reading symbols from /home/user/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/bin/python3.10d...
Illegal process-id: 1681210136_python3.10d_157077.coredump.

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/DumZfE (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/PDGPyD (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/VkNWTC (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/fy65vC (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/nJUyND (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/a9iMwB (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/CklimD (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/DNtZBA (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/r0hhmD (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/0ZiCFA (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/8agmRB (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/gcfMAC (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/OWkBsE (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/4qKfhE (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/xztuAE (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/ijyldD (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/evuz8E (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/Xg9SVB (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/rjpzPA (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/E5pSJA (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/w3ecTD (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/5OqLMB (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/Qh9XlC (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/fqOahE (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/J6a99A (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/6PbLnB (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/L8AzVD (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/ogczVD (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/zYKzwD (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/uPB7vC (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/RUOzPB (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/jhPQxC (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/VQjZZE (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/T22z6B (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/DNpwZD (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/1D8rrD (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/O0fB3C (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/dlItoE (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/BLPLHE (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/DXuP2C (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/78ZscC (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/uDNACC (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/lgGYDA (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/gtrBnE (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/hyc5dD (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/7G99VA (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/V2mTJD (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /dev/shm/r2DB6D (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing
[New LWP 157077]
[New LWP 157082]
[New LWP 162323]
[New LWP 157087]
[New LWP 162439]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/home/user/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/bin/python3.10d /home/user/'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) source ~/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.10-gdb.py
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007f7860199537 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x000056504ac04b4c in fatal_error_exit (status=-1) at ../Python/pylifecycle.c:2553
#3  _Py_FatalErrorFormat (func=func@entry=0x56504adfb040 <__func__.18> "_enter_buffered_busy", format=format@entry=0x56504adfac80 "could not acquire lock for %s at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads") at ../Python/pylifecycle.c:2760
#4  0x000056504ac8863b in _enter_buffered_busy (self=self@entry=0x7f785ff99190) at ../Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:294
#5  0x000056504ac8b5c9 in buffered_flush (self=0x7f785ff99190, args=<optimized out>) at ../Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:825
#6  0x000056504acc3641 in method_vectorcall_NOARGS (func=<method_descriptor at remote 0x7f785ff36ab0>, args=0x7ffc58ee14f8, nargsf=<optimized out>, kwnames=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/descrobject.c:432
#7  0x000056504ab020f5 in _PyObject_VectorcallTstate (tstate=0x56504cebdfb0, callable=<method_descriptor at remote 0x7f785ff36ab0>, args=0x7ffc58ee14f8, nargsf=1, kwnames=0x0) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:114
#8  0x000056504ab0226e in PyObject_VectorcallMethod (name=name@entry='flush', args=args@entry=0x7ffc58ee14f8, nargsf=<optimized out>, nargsf@entry=9223372036854775809, kwnames=kwnames@entry=0x0) at ../Objects/call.c:770
#9  0x000056504ac90b15 in _PyObject_VectorcallMethodId (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=9223372036854775809, args=0x7ffc58ee14f8, name=0x56504aed53c0 <PyId_flush>) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:233
#10 _PyObject_CallMethodIdNoArgs (name=0x56504aed53c0 <PyId_flush>, self=<optimized out>) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:239
#11 _io_TextIOWrapper_flush_impl (self=0x7f78600ca7b0) at ../Modules/_io/textio.c:3044
#12 0x000056504ac90c0d in _io_TextIOWrapper_flush (self=<optimized out>, _unused_ignored=<optimized out>) at ../Modules/_io/clinic/textio.c.h:655
#13 0x000056504acc3641 in method_vectorcall_NOARGS (func=<method_descriptor at remote 0x7f785ff386b0>, args=0x7ffc58ee1608, nargsf=<optimized out>, kwnames=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/descrobject.c:432
#14 0x000056504ab020f5 in _PyObject_VectorcallTstate (tstate=0x56504cebdfb0, callable=<method_descriptor at remote 0x7f785ff386b0>, args=0x7ffc58ee1608, nargsf=1, kwnames=0x0) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:114
#15 0x000056504ab0226e in PyObject_VectorcallMethod (name=<optimized out>, args=args@entry=0x7ffc58ee1608, nargsf=<optimized out>, nargsf@entry=9223372036854775809, kwnames=kwnames@entry=0x0) at ../Objects/call.c:770
#16 0x000056504ac013ea in _PyObject_VectorcallMethodId (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=9223372036854775809, args=0x7ffc58ee1608, name=0x56504aec49f0 <PyId_flush>) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:233
#17 _PyObject_CallMethodIdNoArgs (name=0x56504aec49f0 <PyId_flush>, self=<_io.TextIOWrapper at remote 0x7f78600ca7b0>) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:239
#18 flush_std_files () at ../Python/pylifecycle.c:1597
#19 0x000056504ac0491e in fatal_error (fd=fd@entry=2, header=header@entry=0, prefix=prefix@entry=0x0, msg=msg@entry=0x0, status=status@entry=-1) at ../Python/pylifecycle.c:2727
#20 0x000056504ac04b47 in _Py_FatalErrorFormat (func=func@entry=0x56504adfb040 <__func__.18> "_enter_buffered_busy", format=format@entry=0x56504adfac80 "could not acquire lock for %s at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads") at ../Python/pylifecycle.c:2784
#21 0x000056504ac8863b in _enter_buffered_busy (self=self@entry=0x7f785ff99190) at ../Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:294
#22 0x000056504ac8b5c9 in buffered_flush (self=0x7f785ff99190, args=<optimized out>) at ../Modules/_io/bufferedio.c:825
#23 0x000056504acc3641 in method_vectorcall_NOARGS (func=<method_descriptor at remote 0x7f785ff36ab0>, args=0x7ffc58ee1878, nargsf=<optimized out>, kwnames=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/descrobject.c:432
#24 0x000056504ab020f5 in _PyObject_VectorcallTstate (tstate=0x56504cebdfb0, callable=<method_descriptor at remote 0x7f785ff36ab0>, args=0x7ffc58ee1878, nargsf=1, kwnames=0x0) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:114
#25 0x000056504ab0226e in PyObject_VectorcallMethod (name=name@entry='flush', args=args@entry=0x7ffc58ee1878, nargsf=<optimized out>, nargsf@entry=9223372036854775809, kwnames=kwnames@entry=0x0) at ../Objects/call.c:770
#26 0x000056504ac90b15 in _PyObject_VectorcallMethodId (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=9223372036854775809, args=0x7ffc58ee1878, name=0x56504aed53c0 <PyId_flush>) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:233
#27 _PyObject_CallMethodIdNoArgs (name=0x56504aed53c0 <PyId_flush>, self=<optimized out>) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:239
#28 _io_TextIOWrapper_flush_impl (self=0x7f78600ca7b0) at ../Modules/_io/textio.c:3044
#29 0x000056504ac90c0d in _io_TextIOWrapper_flush (self=<optimized out>, _unused_ignored=<optimized out>) at ../Modules/_io/clinic/textio.c.h:655
#30 0x000056504acc3641 in method_vectorcall_NOARGS (func=<method_descriptor at remote 0x7f785ff386b0>, args=0x7ffc58ee1988, nargsf=<optimized out>, kwnames=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/descrobject.c:432
#31 0x000056504ab020f5 in _PyObject_VectorcallTstate (tstate=0x56504cebdfb0, callable=<method_descriptor at remote 0x7f785ff386b0>, args=0x7ffc58ee1988, nargsf=1, kwnames=0x0) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:114
#32 0x000056504ab0226e in PyObject_VectorcallMethod (name=<optimized out>, args=args@entry=0x7ffc58ee1988, nargsf=<optimized out>, nargsf@entry=9223372036854775809, kwnames=kwnames@entry=0x0) at ../Objects/call.c:770
#33 0x000056504ac013ea in _PyObject_VectorcallMethodId (kwnames=0x0, nargsf=9223372036854775809, args=0x7ffc58ee1988, name=0x56504aec49f0 <PyId_flush>) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:233
#34 _PyObject_CallMethodIdNoArgs (name=0x56504aec49f0 <PyId_flush>, self=<_io.TextIOWrapper at remote 0x7f78600ca7b0>) at ../Include/cpython/abstract.h:239
#35 flush_std_files () at ../Python/pylifecycle.c:1597
#36 0x000056504ac04515 in Py_FinalizeEx () at ../Python/pylifecycle.c:1762
#37 0x000056504aaf2c26 in Py_RunMain () at ../Modules/main.c:668
#38 0x000056504aaf2c76 in pymain_main (args=args@entry=0x7ffc58ee1a30) at ../Modules/main.c:696
#39 0x000056504aaf2cf2 in Py_BytesMain (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at ../Modules/main.c:720
#40 0x000056504aaf16fe in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at ../Programs/python.c:15
(gdb) py-bt
Unable to locate python frame
```

Using the coredump file I can successfully have the python binary backtrace, however I can't have the script backtrace, even though the `py-bt` command is recognized.

I though that maybe the issue was that I wasn't linking the script when calling gdb so I made a second try.

- Second try

This time I launched gdb as I did with the `slow.py` script, and I loaded the coredump once inside gdb.

```
$ gdb --args /home/user/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/bin/python3.10d my_complex_script.py
Reading symbols from /home/user/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/bin/python3.10d...
(gdb) core 1681210136_python3.10d_157077.coredump
    [...]
(gdb) source ~/python_installs/python-3.10.10-debug/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/bin/python3.10-gdb.py
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007f7860199537 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
    [...]
#40 0x000056504aaf16fe in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at ../Programs/python.c:15
(gdb) py-bt
Unable to locate python frame
```

With this approach I have the same result than with the first one.

I can't find a way to get the script backtrace when using a coredump file.

---

- **Questions**

Is it possible to get the python script backtrace using a coredump ?

If not, do I have to run the script within gdb and wait for the error to occur ?

Is there a better method to debug complex python scripts than using gdb ?

Comment: There is twice the function `_Py_FatalErrorFormat` in your backtrace, with `could not acquire lock for %s at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads` in its format argument. So it looks like python was already in the exit phase, which would explain why `py-bt` doesn't show anything.

Comment: You're right, I got other coredumps later and I could get the python backtrace for those using the first method. You can add an answer and I will accept it. Thanks